# How to write a Jpa Specification to join two tables?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, criteria

Say I have Two Entity like below:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "reward")   
public class Reward{

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(generator = "system-uuid")
  @GenericGenerator(name = "system-uuid", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator")
  @Column(length = 36)
  private String id;

  private String sn;

  //other fields

}


@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "strategy_rewards")
public class RewardUserRelation{

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(generator = "system-uuid")
  @GenericGenerator(name = "system-uuid", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator")
  @Column(length = 36)  
  private String id; 

  private String uid;

  private String rid; //reward id

  //other fields;    

}
```

And I have written some other specifications like below to filter my rewards data from mysql and return them to other services:

```
public static Specification<Reward> withSn(String sn) {
    return (root, query, builder) -> builder
        .like(root.get("sn"), "%" +sn + "%");
  }

Page result = rewardRepository.findAll(where(sn == null ? null : 
    RewardSpecs.withSn(sn)), pageable));
```

But now I want to complete a specification which can **filter the reward whose id doesn't appear in the RewardUserRelation Table**, which means these rewards are unused. I have searched several specification tutorials but still can't work it out. Should I use a Join Criteria Api? But I don't know how to do it. :(

**Update**: Somehow I managed to solve this problem by selecting all rid from relation table in advance and use Expression.in(), but still wonder is there a better way to do this.

```
List<String> idList =strategyRewardRelationRepository.getByDeleted(false).stream()
.map(StrategyRewardRelation::getRid).distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());

public static Specification<Reward> withUsed(Boolean used, List<String> idList) {
    return (root, query, builder) -> {
      return used ? root.get("id").in(idList) : root.get("id").in(idList).not();
    };
 }
```

Comment: I'm curious as to why you have a `RewardUserRelation` class as the intermediate table should be handled internally by a `@ManyToMany` relation.

Comment: I don't see any `OneToMany` or `ManyToOne` relationship in your entity classes. Have you removed them intentionally for posting this question and do you have them in your original code? Because criteria joins require association navigation.

Comment: @MadhusudanaReddySunnapu No I haven't used any `OneToMany` or `ManyToOne` annotations

Comment: How are your entities `Reward` and `RewardUserRelation` related? I don't even see any @Entity or @id annotations either? Are you able to save `Reward` entity in the data through your code?

Comment: @MadhusudanaReddySunnapu I added some missed code upside, I can simply save reward by rewardRepository.save()

Comment: You need to update your entities to use OneToMany and ManyToOne and related them property. Subsequently you can go through this link http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/data/120272-specifications-getting-onetomany-entity to use join with specs.

Comment: @MadhusudanaReddySunnapu Thanks man I have worked it out in another way as updated upside but I will also spend some time to try this

Answer (score 0):

Two Joins in the `Specification` may be the way to go:

```
case "propertyId":
                Join<SourceEntity, Item> itemJoin = root.join("item");
                Join<SourceEntity, ItemSourceDetail> itemDetailJoin = itemJoin.join("itemSourceDetail");
                try {
                    filterValue = criteria.getString(key).toString();
                    filters.add(itemDetailJoin.get("propertyId").in(Long.valueOf(filterValue)));
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;
```